# Connection from Linux server to a windows server with a SQL Server DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, odbc

I want to connect from my Linux web server to a SQL Server DB running on a windows server. I have all the right extensions on the Linux box (near as I can tell) and am trying to connect with the following code:

```
<?php

$server = "ip address";
$user = "userName";
$password = "passWord";
$database = "dataBase";

// Connect to MS SQL database.

$conn = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);

If ($conn) {
    echo "Database connection is established.<br />\n";
} 
else {
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />\n";
    die ( print_r(odbc_errormsg(), true));
}
?>
```

I get this error:

> Connection could not be established.
>   [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0' : file not found

I assume that this issue is on the windows machine? I have never made this type of connection before.

What I want to be able to do is connect to this DB from my Linux web server to manipulate the data within that database. (add, edit, delete)

Comment: No, looks like you don't have the driver installed on the Linux machine.

Comment: Also SQL Server <> MySQL. It clearly appears here you are using SQL Server, so please don't tag random other RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Server Native Client ODBC driver is only for Windows. On Linux, install [Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server) (latest version as of this writing). Then specify "Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}" in the connection string.

Comment: Thanks Dan! I am trying this now.

Comment: Hey Dan, I installed the driver but am getting this error now: Connection could not be established.
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server' : file not found

Comment: @AllenAWF, sorry, the driver name should be "ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'" (missed deleting Microsoft when I copied your original connection string). I corrected my answer. You can list the installed drivers with `cat /etc/odbcinst.ini`

Comment: Hey Dan! Thanks! It works! Now to figure out how to write functions that can view, edit and delete ;)

Comment: Hey Dan, Any suggestions on writing a simple query to return the data in a table? I can use odbc_columns to return a list of column names, but can't seem to get it to return the data. The query returns a "can not execute the query" error. I can make another question if needed.

Comment: @AllenAWF, what I don't know about php is a lot but I can say there are many different methods to execute queries and fetch results. I suggest you start by perusing the documentation which often include examples to get you started, like [this page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-object.php). Give that a try and, if you run into problems, ask a new question and include the code you tried.